# Login to admin by frontend form?

Tags: admin, login, front-end

I'm developing a website by wordpress, customer want I build a custom login page and login by email, not username.
And admin page with custom url '/manage/'

Below my code for login:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$user = get_user_by('email', $email);
if (wp_check_password($pass, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID)) {
   wp_set_current_user($user->data->ID, $user->data->user_login);
   wp_set_auth_cookie($user->data->ID);
   do_action( 'wp_login', $user->data->user_login );
   $_SESSION['success'] = 'Hello ' . $user->data->display_name . '!';
   wp_safe_redirect(wp_get_referer());
   exit();
}
```

My problem is:

When I submit, website return success and current user on Frontend changed. But when I try go to admin dashboard, it redirect me to wp-login.php and require me login again. 
I don't what is wrong or how to fix that.

So, please, help me!

Comment: You should avoid using `$_SESSION`, WP doesn't use it and it doesn't work on a lot of hosts

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work - although you should not use `$_SESSION` (as Tom already noted).  Also ID, user_pass, and user_login are all top level in the user object.

Here's what I would try:

```
$email = sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] );
$pass  = $_POST['password'];
$user  = get_user_by( 'email', $email );

if ( wp_check_password( $pass, $user->user_pass, $user->ID ) ) {
   wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
   wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
   do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
   wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
   exit();
}
```